# javascript: JSON.parse date returns wrong date

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have created a web service that returns a JSON string, in one of them is a date field:

```
{  
   "nyear":2015,
   "nperiod":12,
   "ddelivtime":1273474800000,
   "vpoitem":"10",
   "iversion":1,
   "vdsnumber":null,
   "isequence":null
}
```

Particularly `ddelivtime`, which is returned as a timestamp, has a value of **2010-05-10**.

However, when I processed the JSON using `JSON.parse`, the date becomes **2010-04-10**.

Is there something weird that causes the JSON date to be parsed one month short? Because all of my JSON are parsed wrongly now because of this.

Comment: Look this post, it can help you. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates

Comment: JavaScript uses zero-based months, is that what you're seeing?

Comment: How do you get that "date"? Is it a string?

Comment: "However, when I processed the JSON using JSON.parse, the date becomes 2010-04-10" — It won't. It's just a number as far as JSON.parse is concerned. You must be doing something else. Provide an [mcve]

Comment: It was because of zero-based months, which I am pretty much unaware of. Thank you very much.

And to all who downvoted this question, thanks for discouraging me.

Comment: @Quentin I am not doing "anything else". I have stated that those "numbers" are timestamp.

Comment: @NicolasTakashi unfortunately the examples given in the articles are dates which are not in the timestamp format, but a very good information, thanks anyway :)

Comment: It has a value of `1273474800000` not `2010-05-10` or `2010-04-10`.

Comment: @Liam it is a Date in Java. Returned as timestamp in JSON.

Comment: @Quentin ...which is why i wanted to parse that into freaking Date format. It SHOULD return May 10th, 2010 14:00:00

Comment: No...you're misunderstanding, `2010-04-10` is the string representation of a date, not the date. How do you get this string value?

Comment: @cipley — Parsing it will give you a number. If you want to convert that number to a Date you need to do something. Since you said you were getting `2010-05-10` you, presumably, are doing something, but you didn't tell us what. You should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript uses zero based months. So simply get Month value an do plus one into it Like following :

```js
var data = {  
   "nyear":2015,
   "nperiod":12,
   "ddelivtime":1273474800000,
   "vpoitem":"10",
   "iversion":1,
   "vdsnumber":null,
   "isequence":null
}
var d = new Date(data.ddelivtime);
var formatDate = d.getFullYear()+ '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate();

console.log(formatDate);
```

Comment: I was unaware of this. Thank you for the enlightenment